# Visual Studio Mac: how to change spaces per indent setting?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

On VS 2019 for Mac, I would like to set global (and language-level) indent options -- spaces vs tabs and indent size.

Where are these settings configured? I tried Preferences > Text Editor but they aren't anywhere under those options. The [only documentation available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-all-languages-tabs?view=vs-2019) implies they should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out they live under Preferences > Source Code > Code Formatting for some reason. It's not obvious how to set defaults for all languages, but all languages inherit preferences from the "Text file" settings so you can set your defaults there.